# How to dynamically add values in JSON array using index

Tags: arrays, angularjs, list

I am having this format in my script

```
//declaration of JSON object
items= {};
items.values= [];
```

I need a structure like this, which is inserted automatically when the script is executed:

```
    items : 
        {
        key :['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
        values: [1, 2, 3, 4]
        }
```

Since the item.values[0] is undefined, it throws me a undefined error. Can anyone please tell me how to initialize the JSON object, such that it wont throw undefined error

I would like to insert like this:

```
var i=0;
item.key[i]= 'one';
item.values[i]= 1;
```

I am not sure whether this is the best practice, if anyone knows better way please post it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You define the object `items` and then you try to access the object `item`

Comment: Please show more code... `items.values` is already an array but `items.key` is undefined and it seems like you have something backwards in the question. Also this is not a `json object` ... there is no such thing since json is string data

Comment: Sorry about that, items.key =[] is also defined. I need to do like this, var i=0;
item.key[i]= 'one';
item.values[i]= 1;

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea. It looks like your property for adding keys isn't there though. Let's declare two properties, `keys` and `values`.

```
items= {};
items.keys = [];
items.values= [];
```

Our JavaScript object now looks like this

```
{ "keys": [], "values": [] }

var words = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
var numbers = [1,2,3,4];
```

You now want to iterate using a `for`loop. In JavaScript, arrays are 0-indexed, meaning the first element has an index of `0`. That's why we initialize the `i` variable with a value of 0. After every iteration, we increment this variable and then check if it's less than the length of the array.

```
function populateObject() {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        items.keys.push(words[i]);
        items.values.push(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

And then call your function

```
populateObject();
```

Here is the output

```
{"keys": ["one", "two", "three", "four"], "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: I found a way for my problem. Anyway thanks for the answers and comments :)